# Interpolate 2D data

Tags: python, interpolation

I generated a cartesian grid in Python using NumPy's `linspace` and `meshgrid`, and I obtained some data over this 2D grid from an unknown function. I want to get an approximation of the value of the function over some points inside the boundaries of the grid which are not part of it. I do not have some other unstructured grid, I just want to know the value in certain points. I assume I have to *interpolate* the data somehow, but I am very clueless on this and reading the documentation about the `interpolate` module of SciPy and some related components doesn't help. How can I find out this interpolated data?

**Note**: I know what I want to accomplish, but I have never done a task like this before and I have some problems formulating this question in terms of proper concepts and vocabulary. If I am not clear enough please help me improve my question.

Comment: Use the http://orion.math.iastate.edu/burkardt/f_src/bivar/bivar.html Fortran code. I have used it in the past on some fairly large data sets. All you need is a Fortran compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I particularly like the [bivariate spline class](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline) for what I think you are describing. You can use it to make a function (i.e. it is callable at any point) which interpolates the data using a spline. If you want just an interpolation then you simply set the `kx` and `ky` values to 1. If you want a smoother function then increasing the order of the spline (arguably 3 is a good choice) and you can even use a smoothing factor which I never do. The `x` and `y` values you would use are the ones that `linspace` gave you and the `z` value would be the function values.

Answer (score 7):

You can find a good overview of methods and vocabulary on interpolation in two dimensions at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation

Comment: Thank you Arnold! This is indeed very helpful. I am checking this and see if now I can solve the problem, or at least improve the question.

Answer (score 6):

There is a nice video made by Travis Oliphant where he discusses 2D interpolation using python: see the youtube video [Python Interpolation 3 of 4: 2d interpolation with Rbf and interp2d](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cJLVhdj0j4)

Comment: Didn't know the video, thank you for the resource.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have a 2D grid with the X-axis running from ${0,1,...,i,...,M}$ and the Y-axis running from ${0,1,...,j,...,N}$. Each $i,j$ in a non-negative integer.

Your data over the grid can be viewed as a function of the grid locations $(i,j)$. In effect, the data $z = f(i,j)$.

Let's say you want the value of this function at $(i',j')$, where $i'=i+\delta{i}$ and $j'=j+\delta{j}$, such that $\delta{i}$ and $\delta{j}$ are the fractional decimal values between $0$ and $1$. Your problem is to find $z' = f(i',j') = f(i+\delta{i}, j+\delta{j})$.

There are several options for interpolating on such a grid. One of the simplest methods is the nearest neighbor interpolation. In this kind of interpolation, you simply assign to $(i',j')$, the value of the closest grid point. A naive way of doing this is to round $i'$ and $j'$ to the nearest integer.

A slightly better interpolation scheme would use a weighted combination of its closest neighbors that lie on the grid. For example, with linear interpolation, you would use the four closest grid points $(i,j)$, $(i+1,j)$, $(i, j+1)$ and $(i+1,j+1)$ to find the appropriate interpolate value at $(i',j')$.

Answer (score 1):

For fast easy spline interpolation on a uniform grid in 1d 2d 3d and up,
I recommend [scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html);
see the plot and example code under
[multivariate-spline-interpolation-in-python-scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238250/multivariate-spline-interpolation-in-python-scipy) on SO.
For smoothly-varying nonuniform grids, there's a helper class
[Intergrid](http://denis-bz.github.com/docs/intergrid.html) .